# OperationalError: table Student has no column named Fecha

Tags: python, sqlite

I am starting with Tkinter module from python and sqlite3. I am trying to add a new column into my database where i should insert the time with `datetime.datetime.now()` function, but i'm having an OperationalError with the column named *Fecha*

Any suggestion?

Here's the function :

```
def database():
      username = Username.get()
      passw = password.get()
      if (passw == 'abc'): #Just trying an output
         print("ok")
      else :
         sector = area.get()
         prog = var1.get()
         time = datetime.datetime.now()
         conn = sqlite3.connect('Nanotechnology.db')
         with conn:
            cursor=conn.cursor()
         cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student (Username TEXT,Password TEXT,Area TEXT,Programs INT,Fecha TEXT)')
         cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Student (Username,Password,Area,Programs,Fecha) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',(username,passw,sector,prog,time))
         conn.commit()
         Label(root, text= "Succesful Registration", fg="green", font =("bold",12)).place(x=180, y=450)
         sleep(3)
         root.destroy()
```

Comment: Probably the table exists already (without the column). Therefore the "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" does nothing.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks a lot, I just deleted the .db and it works